# How do we add same shapefiles on two or more leaflet maps on same page?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, shapefile

I have two Leaflet maps on the same page and I am trying to load the same shapefile on both of them. On the first one it gets loaded and displayed while on the other it gets loaded but not displayed.

```
mymap = L.map('map_container').setView([24.379311, 88.041001], 15);
mymap2 = L.map('map_container2').setView([24.379311, 88.041001], 15);

L.tileLayer(
     '', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom:1,
}).addTo(mymap);

L.tileLayer(
     '', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom:1,
}).addTo(mymap2);

shpfile = new L.Shapefile('js/world/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3', {
    style: stateStyle
});
shpfile.addTo(mymap);
shpfile.once("data:loaded", function() {
    console.log("finished loaded shapefile");
});

shpfile2 = new L.Shapefile('js/world/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3', {
    style: stateStyle
});
shpfile2.addTo(mymap2);
shpfile2.once("data:loaded", function() {
    console.log("finished loaded shapefile2");
});
```

So in 'mymap' its getting loaded and displayed but in 'mymap2' its just getting loaded but not displayed.

The markers and everything is getting displayed on both of them, its just an issue with the shapefiles.

Can someone please guide me through it?

Thanks.